# Create function in Typescript that given an object will return an object that has keys and values derived from the values of the given object

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I'm trying to wrap my head around types in Typescript. In general it's going well but I'm struggling to convert this function from Javascript to Typescript.

```js
export function keyed(object, key, value) {
  const newKey = object[key];
  const newValue = object[value];
  const newObject = {};
  newObject[newKey] = newValue;
  return newObject;
};
```

This is my attempt so far:

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
export function keyed<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K, value: K): { [key: ValueOf<T>]: ValueOf<T> } {
  const newKey: ValueOf<T> = object[key];
  const newValue: ValueOf<T> = object[value];
  const newObject: { [key: ValueOf<T>]: ValueOf<T> } = {};
  newObject[newKey] = newValue;
  return newObject;
};
```

But, I'm getting a few errors like:

```
An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337)
```

and

```
Type 'ValueOf<T>' cannot be used to index type '{}'.ts(2536)
```

I've tried to use underscores DefinitelyTyped definitions to help out [over here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/underscore/index.d.ts), since they do quite a bit of these operations but I haven't had any luck. Is it impossible?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mx638w) meet your needs?  Test it against the use cases you care about.  If it works I can maybe write up an answer; otherwise please [edit] the question to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: @jcalz please don't encourage people to use type assertions... down that path madness lies! Better to adjust the original implementation code so that no mutation is being done.

Comment: @BenWainwright without a solution to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948 I can't imagine an adjustment that doesn't require the equivalent of a type assertion somewhere.  Do you have one in mind?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIBVzQLxQM7AE4EsB2A5lAD5R4CuAtgEYRYkYg0D2ANgNwBQnEAHmMyzAoAM3J4AxsBzM8UANbwIAEwA8nKFARQ+wCHmXooAJQgTBazLkIAaWPCSQAfDY2wdvPQaOKQzEVqumgBqHl6GCvD+WpxOABTM1ABWZsAAXIGRIBkwdgBuAIas5BAZwQCUGQDeUADavjkOyAC6GQi1wc1QAL5QVdya5niYZBAA7nDZWrUwXWiJKVL18M1cg7IjeOPBRSVtHXNQC6m1hcUQq25uWBDA5Fhy-ZqatVsTKxlvO+dBPVzdnCAA

Comment: I think this probably needs tweaking but it works for me, I think?

Comment: That works for me @BenWainwright! :D 
Thanks you two for shedding some light into what's going on here and best practices as well.

Comment: @BenWainwright but it [breaks the use cases](//tsplay.dev/N53z5W).  You don't necessarily want to require that all values of the object passed in are `PropertyKey`, since `keyed({k: "a", v: true},"k","v"}` should work, right? And you don't want to widen the output all the way to `Record<PropertyKey, SomeValue>` because then you forget all about the specific keys, and then `keyed({k: "a", v: 1},"k","v").oopsie.toFixed()` is not a compile time error but is a runtime error.  If you can come up with a strongly typed output (with known keys) without something like a type assertion, let me know.

Comment: @ajauntyshark Do you want me to write up an answer with [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mx638w) or not?  I don't see how the other code posted here works for you (seems [broken](https://tsplay.dev/N53z5W) to me) so I won't proceed unless I get either the go-ahead from you or a description of what my approach breaks so I can address it.

Comment: @jcalz looks like Ben's approach worked fine for me. You can see [an example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIBVwQGoCYoF4oGdgCcBLAOwHMoAfKYgVwFsAjCfS3ERgewBsBuAKD4AzGsQDGwQh2JQA1vAgATADx8oUBFAgAPYBGIKcUAEoRRHfMrxEyAGljwkkdAD4bq2Jp16Ds+B0Hqbmoonrr6hnIg-up8zgAUHAwAVqbAAFyBviAZMHYAbgCGXDQQGSgAlBkA3lAA2pE5DsjoALoZCLUoLVAAvlBVAmpmxHjUEADucNnqtTDd2Ikp4vXwLfxDUqPEEyhFJe2d81CLqbWFxRBr7u74EMA0+NIDamq125OrGe+7F0G9-D0BMNRossP13BA8npgABJAAiGQARABGNAAZkRfzMInSUAArAAWPg9fh8YHAKC3HA0LgU7CRRQJZJ2ADkkOh8JZrOxxGALPK-GB3AgADouBxSHEqTTgAKgA).

Comment: The result of `console.log()` isn't the issue, though, since that's a runtime concern and even your original version would have compiled to the same code and output the same result at runtime.  If your issue is getting the compiler to have good typing behavior, then I'm very surprised you're happy with the version from that example.  Do you really intend [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mLL2bm) to be in error? Do you really intend [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w1472W) *not* to be in error? Both seem problematic to me.